# How can I set an explicit cookie domain and still login

Tags: magento-1.9, login, cookie

I am setting explicit cookie domain in the config, as my Magento site is on www.mydomain.com and I want to share cookies with a subdomain sub.mydomain.com.

If I leave Magento to set its default cookie domain it will use .www.mydomain.com, which will not share with sub.mydomain.com, so I am setting a manual cookie domain to .mydomain,com (path: "web/cookie/cookie_domain", scope: "default", value: ".mydomain.com").

However, I then get the age-old problem of not being able to log into admin or frontend. I put in my username and password but I do not even get an error back - I'm just returned to the login page.

The conventional Magento wisdom is to clear cookies and make sure that you don't have a manual cookie domain set... except that I *need* a manual cookie domain set.

The domain of the cookie stored is correct as ".mydomain.com" and it is being shared as expected with the sub-domain. But I can't login. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time I finished writing this I spotted my error:

**Magento expects the cookie domain to be entered without the initial "."**

By using "mydomain.com" as my manual cookie domain, I can log in again. On setting the cookies, Magento prefixes a "." so the cookies I see in my browser are ".mydomain.com" and they work exactly the same across sub-domains, but it also recognises the cookies so that login works.