# Login to admin after second attempt only

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, browser

Can't figure out a strange issue. When I access to **site.com/admin** and enter access credentials, Magento redirects me to the login page again.

If I refresh the page or enter login credentials again, I will be redirected to dashboard.

After some inspection, I also noticed, that after the first login, cookie contain two different variables admihntml for **site.com** and **.site.com.**

I think it's the problem, but don't understand how to solve it.

This happened in Chrome only. **FF and Opera are OK.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. According to this answer [How can I set an explicit cookie domain and still login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85257/how-can-i-set-an-explicit-cookie-domain-and-still-login), I change cookie domain to .site.com and now can login without refreshing or second login.